# How to get viewlet by an plone object url

Tags: plone, zope, viewlets

I'm trying to get viewlet belowcontenttitle for an object by its URL.
Something like below, but using object URL instead of 'plone'.

```
id="viewlet-below-content-title" tal:content="structure provider:plone.belowcontenttitle"
```

Can I do it using restrictedTraverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a new view for the `belowcontenttitle` viewlet; template:

```xml
<div tal:content="structure provider:plone.belowcontenttitle"/>
```

registered with:

```xml
<browser:page
    for="*"
    name="belowcontenttitle"
    permission="zope2.View"
    template="template_shown_above.pt"
    />
```

*Then* you can use *that* view with a simple traverse:

```xml
<div tal:replace="structure context/path/to/other/object/@@belowcontenttitle" />
```

This looks up the view in the context of the other object; the template is rendered and returned, replacing the `div`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.
But I still can not concatenate my paths with 'context/'. I have dynamic paths into a list.

Comment: I was able to concatenate the path using:
`<tal:block tal:define="commentaryPath news/path">
    <div tal:replace="structure context/?commentaryPath/@@commentaryView" />
</tal:block>`

Comment: @MatheusPereira: I was in the process of looking up the `?variable` use in path expressions for you. :-)